# Proving that being $S=${$p \in \Bbb R[x] : p(1) = 0 $}. $(S,+,.)$ is a subring of $(\Bbb R[x],+,.)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let  $(\Bbb R[x],+,.)$ a ring and  $S=${$p \in \Bbb R[x] : p(1) = 0 $}. $(S,+,.)$  $⊂$  $\Bbb R[x]$. Let's see that $S$ is a subring of $(\Bbb R[x],+,.)$

(1) $S$ is nonempty: Let $p(x)=a(x)(x-1)$ with $a(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$ then $p(1)=a(1)(1-1)=0 \in S$  so $S$ is nonempty.

(2) Let $p,q \in S$ then $p(1)=0$ and $q(1)=0$. Then, I can write $p$ and $q$ as follows: $p(x) = a(x)(x-1)$ and $q(x)=b(x)(x-1)$ with $a(x),b(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$.

Then $p(x)+q(x)=t(x)= [a(x)(x-1)]+[b(x)(x-1)]=[a(x)+b(x)](x-1)$ $\Rightarrow$ $t(1)=[a(1)+b(1)](1-1)=0.$

So $p+q \in S$

Now, $p(x).q(x)=r(x)=[a(x)(x-1)].[b(x)(x-1)]=[a(x).b(x)](x-1)^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $r(1)=[a(1).b(1)](1-1)^2=0$

So $p.q \in S$

(3) Let $p \in S$ then I can write p as follows: $p(x)=a(x)(x-1)$ with $a(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$. Let $l$  the opposite of $p$ $\Rightarrow$ $l(x)=-a(x)(x-1)$ $\Rightarrow$ $l(1)=-a(1)(1-1)=0$

So $(S,+,.)$ is subring of  $(\Bbb R[x],+,.)$

*Is it correct and is it well demonstrated what I did?*

Comment: Did you check to see if your claimed subring contains the multiplicative identity from the parent ring?

Comment: @quasi  How would that be?
I verified the following: $A'$ is subring of $(A, +,.)$ If and only if $(1) 0 ∈ A' (2) (x ∈ A '∧ y ∈ A') → (x + y ∈ A ' ∧ x .y ∈ A ')$ and $(3) x ∈ A' → -x ∈ A '$

Comment: It depends on the book in use. Does the author require rings to have an element qualifying as a multiplicative $1$? Most introductory texts make that one of the required conditions.

Comment: @quasi yes it requires it because it asks that (A,.) be a semigroup. Then how would you prove the existence of the neutral for the multiplication in this case of plinomies?

Comment: A multiplicative semigroup need not have a multiplicative identity. As regards $R[x]$, assuming $1\in R$, the constant polynomial $p(x)=1$ is the element qualifying as $1$ in $R[x]$.

Comment: Bottom line: If rings are not required to have an element qualifying as $1$, then your proof is basically OK. It depends on the definitions for the given course. Are you using a textbook? If so, which one?

Comment: By the way, you have a minor error in your factorization of $p(x)q(x)$; it should be $a(x)b(x)(x-1)^2$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I checked and yes required that $1$ $\in S$  How would it be working in this case with polynomials? What is the error in that factorization?

Comment: $a(x)(x-1)b(x)(x-1)=a(x)b(x)(x-1)^2$

Comment: So is the constant polynomial $p(x)=1$ in the proposed subring?

Comment: Yes I'm using a textbookk is "Notas de Álgebra y matemática discreta" by Liliana Alcón. As seen in the title, it is in Spanish

Comment: No, the constant polynomial ($p(x)=1$) isn't in the subring

Comment: It isn't in the _proposed_ subring. So then it's not actually a subring. Done! (A subring is required to contain the multiplicative $1$ of the parent ring).

Comment: In the end it was not a subring! I have to be more careful. Thank you very much!